# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null in TemplateBase2 Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, devextreme, npm-package

I'm encountering an issue in a React application where the TemplateBase2 component is throwing an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null" error. The error specifically points to the registerPlugin method being called on a null value. I've reviewed the TemplateBase2 code but cannot modify it directly. The error seems related to the pluginHost context. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

I've ensured the correct usage of the **`TemplateBase2`** component and verified that the necessary props are being passed. I also checked the context setup, but the **`pluginHost`** seems to be null when the **`registerPlugin`** method is called. I expected the component to register the plugin successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you've uploaded DevExtreme React Grid to an npm package and are facing issues, make sure to download the necessary packages to ensure compatibility. Include the following dependencies in your project's package.json:

```
"@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^4.0.6",
"@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^4.0.6",
"@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^4.0.6",
```

This ensures that you have the required versions of @devexpress/dx-react-core, @devexpress/dx-react-grid, and @devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui installed.

Remember to run npm install or yarn install after updating your package.json to fetch and install the specified versions.

This should resolve any compatibility issues you might be facing with DevExtreme React Grid